# Is MVCContrib dead?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, mvccontrib

I realize this is a subjective question, but is MVCContrib dead?  The NuGet package has had no updates since 2011, so normally I would consider a project like that dead and likely replaced by something else (i.e. something I should go find and use).  I see there are infrequent commits, but having no NuGet package updates is strange.

But I can't find any alternatives for the basic requirement of wanting DRY links and redirects in MVC (i.e. using lambdas over strings for things like ActionLink and RedirectToAction).  Has the Microsoft MVC team integrated these features in some hidden namespace that I don't realize?  And if not, does anyone know why not?  I would have liked to have seem the string-based methods deprecated by now...

Comment: Where did you get that latest update was on 2011? So far I see is an active project as you can see on commit history http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets. Probably is not as an active as on early stages because they think is enough with the current features.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Ah, I did overlook that.  But one commit in the entire calendar year is still pretty sparse.  And the NuGet package hasn't been updated since 2011.  It's probably more "alive" than these things make me feel, but I think the question is still warranted.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi that is immensely helpful.  Especially since the last download on the project page is also from 2011, so I was led astray.  Highly recommend you post that as the answer to the question.  IMO that is the answer I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I see, it is an active project as you can see on [commit history](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets). Probably it's not as an active as it was on early stages, it might be possible they think is enough with current features.

Also, take into account that there are nuget packages for every mvc version. For instance, latest one is for [MVC 5](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcContrib.Mvc5) and publish date is on 2013-11-21